# Какой самый быстрый алгоритм поиска

Tags: массивы, поиск, алгоритм, c++

Для массивов данных в C++? Интересуют больше всего массивы строк именно.

Comment: @pol500, если Вы о вчерашнем поиске в словаре из 15000 слов, то IMHO проблема не в поиске, конечно если Вы не применяли линейный поиск или в случае хэширования очень маленькую таблицу и разрешение коллизий цепочками.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Самые быстрые для чего и где?
Если отсортированных данных - бинарный поиск и его модификации.

Неотсортированных - хешмап.

Очень больших - mapreduce (это когда данные разделяются между несколькими серверами и каждый делает поиск в своей порции. Потом результаты объединяются).

А ещё можно вначале загрузить данные в какую-нибудь базу данных и пусть это будут ее проблемы:)

Comment: А как вы оцените бинарный поиск по отсортированному в порядке возрастания массиву (коллекции) хеш-ключей? Или так делают только быдло-кодеры?

Comment: у бинарного поиска очень хорошая скорость (максимальное кол-во сравнений - двоичный логарифм от размера данных).
Если сделать нормальный массив хешключей, то поиск можно сделать ещё быстрее. Все очень сильно зависит от задачи.

Answer (score 8):

*Из вариантов специализированных структур данных:*

> [**Radix tree**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) и [**Prefix tree.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) Оба дерева выполняют операцию `lookup` за `O(k)`, где `k` - максимальная длина строки.

*Из вариантов, всегда доступных под рукой в `C++03` / `C++11`*:

> Сортированный `std::vector` + `std::binary_search, std::set` (или `std::map`)`,` `boost::unordered_set`.
>
> Обычно производительности *стандартных контейнеров* хватает для эффективного решения большинства практических задач.

Answer (score 0):

Совсем недавно делал такую штуку. Сделал очень просто. Для строки рассчитывается хэш-сумма. Потом берем остаток от деления хэш-суммы на вместимость массива строк. И пытаемся пихнуть эту строку сначала именно в эту ячейку! Если она занята - идем вправо, пока не найдем свободную. Соответственно, при поиске строки в массиве используем тот же алгоритм. Это проще, чем сортировать хэши и использовать бинарный поиск, и эффективнее, чем просматривать массив хэшей с начала до конца. Хотя в худшем случае, конечно, именно этим все и кончится, но этот случай маловероятен, особенно если сделать массив больше, чем надо, а не впритык. То есть если надо хранить 15000 строк, делаем массив 20000-30000.

Надеюсь, я понятно объяснил. Вот С-подобный псевдокод для иллюстрации идеи (операции со строками, конечно, я делал иначе, через свои велосипеды, мне просто лень расписывать):

```
struct string {
    char symbols[20];
    unsigned long hash;
}

struct string strings[15000]; // Надо инициализировать symbols пустыми строками.

int put_string(char* s)
{
    unsigned long h = hash(s);
    int i = h % 15000;
    while( strings[i].symbols == "" ) {
        if( ++i == 15000 ) i = 0;
    } // Здесь возможно зацикливание, если вместимости массива strings не хватит.
    strings[i].symbols = s;
    return i;
}

int get_string(char* s)
{
    unsigned long h = hash(s);
    int i = h % 15000;
    while( strings[i].symbols != "" ) {
        if( strings[i].hash == h && strings[i].symbols == s ) return i;
        if( ++i == 15000 ) i = 0;
    } // Здесь тоже может произойти зацикливание. Либо нужно использовать цикл for, либо массив strings должен быть гарантированно больше, чем нужно, хотя бы на один элемент. Мне нравится второе.
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: @VadimTukaev, это идея называется [хэширование методом с открытой адресацией](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D1%8D%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0#.D0.9E.D1.82.D0.BA.D1.80.D1.8B.D1.82.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.B0.D0.B4.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F).

На самом деле там еще есть тонкие моменты (например с удалением).

--

Кстати, а Вы вообще-то свой код хотя бы компилировать пробовали?

Comment: > идея называется хэширование методом с открытой адресацией.

Идея была не в алгоритме, а в том, чтобы посоветовать человеку использовать его. Я знал, что такое уже есть, просто забыл название.

> На самом деле там еще есть тонкие моменты (например с удалением).

Признаком отсутствия строки является тот факт, что строка пустая. Поэтому удалять элементы можно, просто присваивая пустую строку.

> Кстати, а Вы вообще-то свой код хотя бы компилировать пробовали?

Конкретно этот - нет. Я же предупредил, что это всего лишь псевдокод для демонстрации идеи. Но аналогичный пробовал не далее как вчера.